# Exemple de trompe oreille

Tags: phrase, jeux-de-mots, homophone

J'ai entendu parler d'une phrase impossible à écrire, ou plutôt, qui peut être écrite de plusieurs façons pour produire plusieurs sens (certains complètement farfelus, mais peu importe). Je crois que ça commence par "L'eusses-tu cru/Lustucru..." mais je ne me souviens pas du reste. Y-a-t'il d'autres exemples de ce genre de phrase, où ce que l'on entend peut être écrit de plusieurs façons différentes (et grammaticalement valides)?

Comment: Est-ce ceci ? https://www.facebook.com/Projet.Voltaire/photos/a.167527220024125/828513163925524/

Comment: On appelle ça un trompe oreille. La dictée impossible est souvent ce qui qualifié la dictée de Mérimée.

Comment: @None Oui c'est vrai. Celle de Mérimée. Bernard Pivot faisait aussi des dictées très difficiles :-) Malheureusement, je n'ai pas accès à Facebook.

Comment: @None J'édite le titre pour "trompe oreille".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Lustucru que mon père fut lapin, il était trop pomme de terre pour aimer les tamarins.

> L'eusses-tu cru que mon père fut là, peint, il était trop homme de terre pour aimer l'état marin.

- Do mi si la do ré fa si la si ré fa si la si mi ré si la si ré do ré<sup>1</sup>

> Domicile adoré, facile à cirer, facile à s’y mirer si la cire est dorée.

- Il est ouvert.

> Il est tout vert.

La plupart des trompe-oreilles que je connais ne sont que des virelangues. Mais au moins pour ces trois là on peut écrire ce qu'on entend de façons différentes.

Wikipedia a un article [trompe-oreille](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trompe-oreilles).

Et encore un pour que @livresque nous fasse [un beau dessin](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/53046/exemple-de-trompe-oreille#comment111418_53047) :

- `œ̃vɛrvɛrsyrœ̃vɛrvɛr`

> Un verre vert sur un ver vert.

> Un ver vert sur un verre vert.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Je suis d'accord que dire que cette phrase est « grammaticalement valide » est très contestable !</sup>

Comment: Très bien! Le premier m'est revenu maintenant - c'est celui-là que j'avais entendu. Le deuxième est encore plus spectaculaire. Merci! :-)

Comment: @livresque _bons exemples_ peut-être? (masculin :-)

Comment: De très bons exemples. J'aime dessiner l'image d'un tiroir vert et ouvert et poser la question. Puis /takatitakite/ : *Ta Katie t'a quitté / ... t'as quitté ? / t'as qui t'es*

Comment: @None les exemples sur la page wikipedia ne semblent pas tous correspondre à l'effet recherché. Est-ce bien de "tromp oreilles" dont il s'agit?

Comment: @Frank non , comme je le dis dans ma réponse pour moi ce sont des virelangues. Tout depend comment on classe. [« les trompe-oreilles sont aussi le plus souvent des virelangues !](https://www.opalivres.fr/la-collection/des-4-ans/virelangues-et-trompe-oreilles-%E2%99%A5/)

Answer (score 2):

Dans le même genre,

```
Gal, amant de la reine, alla, tour magnanime,
Galamment de l'Arène à la Tour Magne à Nîmes.
```

ou

```
Le vieil armagnac / le vieillard maniaque
```

cf. aussi https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vers_holorimes

Comment: Je connaissais une version plus longue avec une variante: Galamment de l'arène à la Tour Magne à Nîmes, par les bois du djinn où s'entasse de l'effroi, Gal, amant de la reine à l'atour magnanime, parle et boit du gin ou cent tasses de lait froid.

Comment: @AnneAunyme Impressionnant !